# Comunicación entre Pipes en C

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en C que intercambia comunicaciones entre procesos padre e hijo. Para ello he creado dos pipes, en el primero escriben y leen padre e hijo y en el segundo solo escribe el hijo, en este caso un número random que va desde 0 a 100. El padre lo lee. El caso es que el mensaje del hijo respondiendo al padre no me lo saca por pantalla, directamente el Buffer2 sale en blanco y no muestra nada. El mensaje del padre al hijo y el número random que recibe el padre los muestra correctamente. Si alguien puede echarme un cable lo agradecería inmensamente, porque soy muy novato en esto de C y no paro de darle vueltas al código.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>

int main(void) {

    int fd[2];
    int fd2[2];

    pid_t pid;

    char saludoPadre[] = "Buenos días hijo.";   //Saludo del padre
    int tamSaludoPadre = strlen(saludoPadre);
    char buffer[tamSaludoPadre];

    char despedidaHijo[] = "Adiós papá."; //Saludo del hijo
    int tamDespedidaHijo = strlen(despedidaHijo);
    char buffer2[tamDespedidaHijo];

    srand (time(NULL)); //Número aleatorio
    int num = rand() % 101;

    char numRandom[3];
    sprintf(numRandom, "%d", num);

    int tamNumeroRandom = strlen(numRandom);
    char buffer3[tamNumeroRandom];

    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd2);

    pid = fork(); //Creo proceso hijo

    switch(pid) {
        case -1: //ERROR AL CREAR EL HIJO
            printf("No se ha podido crear hijo...\n");  
            exit(-1);
        break;
        case 0: //Proceso hijo
            close(fd[1]);

            printf("\tEl hijo recibe la información:\n");
            read(fd[0], buffer, tamSaludoPadre);
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer);

            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], despedidaHijo, tamDespedidaHijo);

            close(fd2[0]);
            write(fd2[1], numRandom, tamNumeroRandom);

        break;
        default: //Proceso padre
            close(fd[0]);
            printf("El padre envía un mensaje al hijo...\n");
            write(fd[1], saludoPadre, tamSaludoPadre);

            wait(NULL);

            printf("El hijo envía un mensaje al padre...\n");
            printf("\tEl padre recibe la información:\n");
            close(fd[1]);
            read(fd[0], buffer2, tamDespedidaHijo);     
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer2);

            printf("El hijo envía un mensaje al padre...\n");
            printf("\tEl padre recibe la información:\n");
            close(fd2[1]);
            read(fd2[0], buffer3, tamNumeroRandom);
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer3);

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hace tiempo que no trabajo con pipes y no recuerdo el funcionamiento exacto, pero hay algo en el código que me suscita dudas. En el código del padre, escribes en primer lugar:

```
close(fd[0]);
```

Esto por tanto cierra en el proceso del padre el flujo de entrada asociado a dicho descriptor de fichero. Sin embargo, un poco más tarde escribes:

```
read(fd[0], buffer2, tamDespedidaHijo);
```

Esto trata de leer desde el flujo de entrada que justo acabas de cerrar. Entiendo que esto es lo que genera el problema. Para solucionarlo, el hijo debería escribir en las dos ocasiones a través del flujo de salida asociado a fd2[1] y el padre debería leer en las dos ocasiones del flujo de entrada asociado a fd2[0].

El código debería quedar así (no lo he probado):

```
        case 0: //Proceso hijo
            close(fd2[0]);
            close(fd[1]);

            printf("\tEl hijo recibe la información:\n");
            read(fd[0], buffer, tamSaludoPadre);
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer);


            write(fd2[1], despedidaHijo, tamDespedidaHijo);
            write(fd2[1], numRandom, tamNumeroRandom);

        break;
        default: //Proceso padre
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd2[1]);

            printf("El padre envía un mensaje al hijo...\n");
            write(fd[1], saludoPadre, tamSaludoPadre);

            wait(NULL);

            printf("El hijo envía un mensaje al padre...\n");
            printf("\tEl padre recibe la información:\n");
            read(fd2[0], buffer2, tamDespedidaHijo);     
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer2);

            printf("El hijo envía un mensaje al padre...\n");
            printf("\tEl padre recibe la información:\n");
            read(fd2[0], buffer3, tamNumeroRandom);
            printf("\t\t%s\n", buffer3);

        break;
```

La idea es que el pipe asociado a fd lo use el padre para escribir y el hijo para leer, y que el pipe asociado a fd2 lo use el hijo para escribir y el padre para leer. Por tanto, es buena práctia cerrar los flujos que cada uno de ellos no va a usar al principio de su bloque de código.

Un saludo y suerte!

Comment: ¡Gracias por la ayuda! A ver si tengo un rato y lo pruebo.